# How to provide the value of a @Nested property of a gradle task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

The gradle doc describes the `@Nested` annotation for custom gradle tasks:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_annotations

Unfortunately, there is no complete example of this mechanism in terms of how it is used in a `build.gradle` file. I created a project to demonstrate a strange exception that happens whenever gradle configures the project:
https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/gradle-nested-property-test

The [build.gradle](https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/gradle-nested-property-test/blob/master/build.gradle) has the following:

```groovy
task T(type: NestedTest) {
    tool = file('x')
    metadata = {
        a = "1"
    }
}
```

The `NestedTest` custom task is in the `buildSrc` folder:

```groovy
class NestedTest extends DefaultTask {

    @InputFile
    public File tool

    @Nested
    @Input
    public Metadata metadata

    @TaskAction
    def run() throws IOException {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

The important bit is the `@Nested` property whose type is really basic:

```
class Mlang-groovyetadata {
    String a
}
```

When I execute the following: `./gradlew tasks`, I get this:

```
Build file '/opt/local/github.me/gradle-nested-property-test/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-nested-property-test'.
> Cannot cast object 'build_6wy0cf8fn1e9nrlxf3vmxnl5z$_run_closure4$_closure5@2bde737' with class 'build_6wy0cf8fn1e9nrlxf3vmxnl5z$_run_closure4$_closure5' to class 'Metadata'
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and how to make this work?

- Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the unit tests in Gradle's source code, I found that the syntax for `@Nested` properties requires invoking the type constructor in the `build.gradle` file.

That is, the following works:

```groovy
task T(type: NestedTest) {
    tool = file('x')
    metadata = new Metadata(
        a: "1"
    )
}
```